# How to install downloaded app?

Tags: software-installation

In Windows there is a wizard for the installation. How does that work in Linux/Ubuntu?

Example: I downloaded `https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.4/node-v14.17.4-linux-x64.tar.xz`. How can I install it and use it?

Comment: See [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) and the project's own instructions [Building Node.js on supported platforms](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md#building-nodejs-on-supported-platforms)

Comment: To add to the above, there's no real mandated standard or anything - each project can package its software how it likes and the installation will vary with each. If the package ends in .deb, that's about the easiest as you can normally just use gedit to install it or even use apt int he terminal to install it.

Comment: See https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation for installation instructions for node.js